# Why does the $PATH of an ssh remote command differ from that of an interactive shell?

Tags: ssh, debian, bash

I have a user that has made no modifications to the $PATH in any dot-files: it is exactly the system default setting. From a login shell:

```
$ ssh example.com
user@example.com:~$ cat /tmp/hello.hs
#!/bin/bash

echo "$SHELL"
echo "$PATH"

user@example.com:~$ /tmp/hello.hs
/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Exactly as specified in `/etc/profile`. This I find rather unexpected:

```
$ ssh example.com '/tmp/hello.sh'
/bin/bash       
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

Like I said, there's no modification of $PATH in `~/.bashrc`, nor in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. No `~/.ssh/environment` either. The `ssh(1)` declares that the environment variable `PATH` is

> Set to the default PATH, as specified when compiling ssh.

but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works) from StackOverflow and this [mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2008/Jun/msg00267.html) article suggest that I *should* be able to influence the $PATH for a given command simply by modifying /etc/profile, one of the shell startup files, etc.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `ssh(1)` manual page: *"If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell."*

So in short when you actually login to the machine bash is started as a login shell and loads the apropriate files, when you connect remotely and issue a command it is run in the place of bash, which means that these files do NOT load. You can work around it with using `su -l -c` or similar in the command part of ssh.

In some cases I've seen `-t` argument to ssh work (allocate tty) too.

**Edit 1**:
I think the PATH information you found, that the default path (unless we override it) is the one compiled into sshd. I made sure that my /etc/profile, /etc/bash*, local dotfiles, etc. didn't have any PATH information in it, then I logged on and still had a PATH. I searched for this one in sshd and found it there. So its how the manpage says:

```
ahnberg@remote$ strings /usr/sbin/sshd | grep -i x11 | grep bin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

Then I add `PATH=$PATH:/my/test` to the very top of my `.bashrc` file on remote, and check it again:

```
ahnberg@local$ ssh ahnberg@remote "env | grep PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/my/test
```

So I can absolutely influence it, and default PATH is the one compiled into sshd. :)

Comment: Hmm, that phrase "executed on the remote host" means a lot more than it says, I think. The more interesting bit, which I missed earlier, comes in the 'ENVIRONMENT' section of the same manpage: "PATH  Set to the default PATH, as specified when compiling ssh." Except [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940533/how-do-i-set-path-such-that-ssh-userhost-command-works) suggests that I _should_ be able to influence the PATH of a command.

Comment: Well the point is that its not a login shell so it doesn't run/source/include the startup files the same way as for a login shell, hence my suggestions to try out. Putting things in `.bashrc` might work too, but overall I'd work around it if PATH is important. Or why not just specify full pathnames if you have a need for the 'command' way of running ssh? :)

Comment: I've edited my post slightly. Now, there's a login shell, a non-login shell and interactive/non-interactive variants thereof. SSH commands are invoked in the user's shell in non-interactive non-login form. The `bash(1)` INVOCATION suggests that no startup files are read in this fashion, but I can't find documentation on _how_ ssh is invoking the shell. This seems counter to the linked sources above, unless others have /etc/ssh/sshrc startup file sourcing that I don't have. (There are workarounds, of course, but the point is understanding exactly how Debian SSHD handles paths by default.)

Comment: If I modify PATH in `/etc/profile` on my remote box path updates for me, so `ssh user@remotebox 'env'` shows me the updated PATH. The same thing goes if I add `export PATH=$PATH:/my/testpath` to .bashrc (but in my case in top of the file before checks for interactive shells (`-z "$PS1"`).

Comment: Updated with my tests/findings.

Comment: Ah ha. SSH is invoking bash as an interactive, non-login shell and my edits to /etc/profile are only picked up by a login shell, according to the INVOCATION documentation. That's the trick, then: I was modifying the wrong startup files.

Comment: Can anyone give an example of how to get the user path with `su -l -c` without the need to specify the username?

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get ssh to run commands using the remote path by running:

```
ssh dist@d6 "bash --login -c 'env'"
```

Here env can be replaced with what ever command you'd like.

I have authorized keys so didn't need a password to run the command or ssh.

Comment: This does not work for me. I still get "command not found" when trying to run a command from the user path.

Comment: Finally man, after 1000 questions this is the one. Thanks very much

Comment: I had to combine it with `-t`: `ssh -t dist@d6 "bash --login -c 'env'"`

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a different solution to fix the problem.
My personal preference is to create new configuration files instead of altering existing ones. This way I can easier destinquish changes from the default configuration.

Here are the contents of `/etc/profile.d/ssh_login.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then
    echo "User '$USER' logged in from '${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}'"
    . /etc/environment
fi
```

Using `dropbear` in place of `openssh-server` (this should also work with openssh), the SSH_CONNECTION variable gets set automatically when I log in remotely. I created a new shell profile configuration to detect SSH logins, display some information on the screen and, most importantly, load the global environment settings from `/etc/environment` to replace the compiled-in values. Please note that this only affects interactive SSH shells, not remote command execution.

**Alternatively**, if you use openssh and always want load the global environment, regardless of whether it is an interactive shell, you could place a symlink in `~/.ssh/` like this:

```
ln -s /etc/environment ~/.ssh/environment
```

Then you need to enable the `PermitUserEnvironment` option in `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`. Only do this for trusted users though, as this could enable them to bypass access restrictions in some configurations using mechanisms such as LD_PRELOAD. Please see `man sshd_config` for more information, specifically how to use `Match` blocks to constraint options to specific users/groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the profile path to load, try:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

at the top of the script. That way the shell is in interactive mode when running the script.

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may
>   be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: And how do you do it in a non-interactive way, but in a login shell?