# PATHs seem incorrect when pssh to remote servers

Tags: google-compute-engine

On GCE, I have 3 VMs and I can use `ssh` to access them from one of them.
I've installed Cassandra on them and configured `PATH` environment variable in `~/.bash_profile`.

**~/.bash_profile:**

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export CASSANDRA_HOME=/opt/apache-cassandra-3.11.1
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7
PATH=$PATH:$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
export PATH
```

Running `echo $PATH` and getting `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/nmj/.local/bin:/home/nmj/bin:/opt/apache-cassandra-3.11.1/bin:/opt/spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin:/opt/spark-2.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/sbin` means it's **correct**.

But when running `pssh -h hosts.txt -l nmj -i 'echo $PATH'`, I only got
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`.
`$PATH` looks **incorrect** here.

So I couldn't use `pssh` to execute ssh in parallel to start up `cassandra`, like `pssh -h hosts.txt -l nmj -i cassandra`, because of `bash: cassandra: command not found`.

How to configure `$PATH` correctly?

**Solution:**
In my opinion, `pssh` will start a **non-login shell**. So it'll not load `~/.bash_profile` file. Then when I defined these variables in `~/.bashrc` file, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer might be here [Why does the $PATH of an ssh remote command differ from that of an interactive shell?](https://serverfault.com/questions/351731/why-does-the-path-of-an-ssh-remote-command-differ-from-that-of-an-interactive-s)

Basically, because you're running a command as an argument, you are not actually opening a shell, so the files are not loaded, and the `PATH` variable is loaded with those files.

What you could do is source these files before running the cassandra command, and it may work

```
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Following your suggestion, this command worked for me where my .bashrc defines a custom $PATH, aliases etc. I'm using under Ubuntu 21.04: pssh -i -h hosts "source /home/<user>/.profile; source /home/<user>/.bashrc; mycommand"